# How do I call a UDF that returns an array within another UDF?

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

I am having some trouble figuring out how to return an array within a UDF from another UDF. The one here is a simple exponential moving average UDF and I am trying to return the array into another UDF but I am getting #value error. I feel there is a simple solution that I am not seeing. All help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
Function ema(arg1 As Variant, ByVal lngth As Long) As Variant
    x = arg1
    dim avg As Double

    avg = 1

    Dim arrema As Variant
    arrema = Array()
    ReDim arrema(1 To UBound(x, 1), 1 To 1)

    For j = 1 To (UBound(x, 1) - lngth)
        For i = (1 + j - 1) To (lngth + j - 1)
            avg = (WorksheetFunction.Index(x, i, 1) + 1) * avg
        Next i
        arrema(j, 1) = avg ^ (1 / lngth)
        avg = 1
    Next j
    'ema = avg ^ (1 / lngth)
    ema = arrema
End Function

Function test(arg2 As Variant, xlength As Long)
    Dim arra As Variant
    'Call ema(arg2, xlength)
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array()
    ReDim arr(1 To UBound(arg2, 1), 1 To 1)

    arra = ema(arg2, xlength)

    For i = 1 To UBound(arg2, 1) - xlength
        arr(i, 1) = arra(i, 1)
    Next i

    test = arr
End Function
```

Comment: first parameter for test function expects arrary. **=test({1,2,3,4,5,9},10)**

Comment: Not quite sure I follow, I am passing the same array in arg1 as in arg2.

Comment: What values are you passing in to get this error?

Comment: What are trying to return? An array is what you'll get and won't display in excel unless you use an aggregate function like sum.

Comment: I just wrote the test function to specifically figure out how handle returning an array from a UDF from within another UDF. The below answer cleared up my issues and the code is working now. I am passing a range of data in both 'arg1' and 'arg2' and just the length of the EMA in 'lngth' and 'xlength'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling `test` from a formula with a range as the `arg1` parameter, then your problem is you are treating a `Range` as if it were an `Array` by calling `UBound(arg2,1)`

Change that to `UBound(arg2.Value,1)` and it will work.

**Further explanation:**

By declaring the `arg#` parameters as `Variant` allows the UDFs to be called with either `Range`'s or `Array`'s.  It may be better to be specific by using either `As Range` or `As Variant()`.

In `Function ema` this issue is avoided by the line `x = arg1`:  If `arg1` is a `Range` then this copies the default property of the Range which is the `Value` property to `x`, making `x` an array.    If `arg1` is an `Array` then it just copies that array into `x`.

Net result is `Function ema` can handle either Ranges or Arrays.  There is another issue there though: `WorksheetFunction.Index(x, i, 1)` will fail with one dimensional Arrays.  Change it to `WorksheetFunction.Index(x, i)` or better still `Application.Index(x, i)` to avoid this issue too.